# Regex for Parsing JSON

Tags: regex, nlp, tableau-api, regex-lookarounds

I have a column of data I'm reading in Tableau directly from Redshift. This column contains a JSON object. It looks like this:

```
{"Age": 58, "City": "Wisconsin Rapids", "Race": "Other", "State": "Wisconsin", "Gender": "Female", "Country": "United States"}
```

I wish to extract this data by generating a column with a calculated field for each data point of interest using Tableau's REGEXP_EXTRACT function. I.e. an Age column, a City column etc.

How do I write a line of regular expressions to get the value of 58 for Age, Wisoncsin Rapids for City, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not using a JSON parser?

Comment: I'm looking to visualize this data in Tableau. Do you mean a parser within the software?

Comment: So it looks like Tableau has native JSON parsing built in, does this look like it'll help your situation? https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/9/your-json-data-ready-analysis-tableau-101-59543

Comment: Just clarified in the post, my data is coming from Redshift. It's a column whose values are a JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex :

```
"Age"\s?+:\s?+"?([[:alnum:]\s]+)"?
```

to extract its value here Age for example

if you want other key for example State use State instead of Age

```
"State"\s?+:\s?+"?([[:alnum:]\s]+)"?
```

you'll find the value of the key in the first group 
See here https://regex101.com/r/KA7PSl/2