# Does Tableau support complex data type of hive columns and flatten it?

Tags: hive, tableau-api

I am trying to create a dashboard from the data present in the Hive. The catch is the column which I want to visualize is a nested JSON type. So will tableau able to parse and flatten the JSON column and list out all possible attributes? thanks!

Comment: Any luck here? If you were able to find an answer on your own please post it and give the green check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Tableau will not automatically flatten the JSON structure of the field for you, but you can manually do so.

[Here](https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-6267) is an article that explains the use of Regex within Tableau to extract pertinent information from your JSON field.

I realize this may not be the answer you were looking for, but hopefully it gets you started down the right path.

(In case it helps, Tableau does have a JSON connector in the event you are able to connect directly to your JSON as a datasource instead of embedded in your Hive connection as a complex field type.)

Comment: Tableau does have a JSON connector that can flatten common structures.

Comment: A connector, yes, but not one that parses fields. If your entire dataset was JSON you could use the connector.

Comment: Here is a link to a good parallel question which exemplifies the method in this answer. In the comments it also shows the confusion between parsing a JSON column and parsing JSON as a datasource.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51085139/regex-for-parsing-json

Comment: Ok, i clearly read too quickly and missed that key point. Sorry. Will upvote when time limit allows

Comment: Thank you - and I have edited answer to include the JSON connector as a consideration and to remove equivocation.